# How to get data of specific item of spinner item

Tags: android, spinner, getter-setter

I have a spinner in which i have added data items from JSON as

```
    JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(strServerResponse);
                    JSONObject jsonObj = arr.getJSONObject(0);
                    ArrayList<String> tii = new ArrayList<String>();
                    ArrayList<String> tiiN = new ArrayList<String>();
                    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
                        pojo = new Pojo();
                        JSONObject jobj2 = arr.getJSONObject(i);
                        String disc = jobj2.optString("name");
                        Log.e("Distttt", "" + disc);
                        String idd = jobj2.optString("id ");
                        // tii.add("Select District");
                        tiiN.add(idd);
                        tii.add(disc);

                    }

                    List<String> listTemp = tii;
                    Set<String> temp = new HashSet<String>(listTemp);
                    List<String> listTempN = tiiN;
                    Set<String> tempN = new HashSet<String>(listTempN);

                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("MyPref3", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                    temp.addAll(listTemp);
                    tempN.addAll(listTempN);
                    editor.putStringSet("title", temp);
                    editor.putStringSet("iddd", temp);
                    editor.commit();
```

each data consists of a id and title.

I am adding those to spinner as

```
   @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        nDialog.dismiss();
        //////////////////////////////////
        Pojo pojo;
        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("MyPref3", MODE_PRIVATE);
        Set<String> set = prefs.getStringSet("title", null);
        Set<String> setN = prefs.getStringSet("iddd", null);

        List<String> titlesList = new ArrayList<String>(0);
        titlesList.addAll(set);

        List<String> descList = new ArrayList<String>(0);
        descList.addAll(setN);

        //servicces.clear();

        for (int i=0;i<set.size();i++) {
            pojo = new Pojo();
            pojo.setSpinnerDistrict(titlesList.get(i));
            pojo.setSpinnerDistrictId(descList.get(i));
            service.add(pojo);
           // ssservice.add(p);
        }
        service.clear();
        ssservice.clear();
        for (String p : set) {
            pojo = new Pojo();

            pojo.setSpinnerDistrict(p);
            service.add(pojo);
            ssservice.add(p);
        }
        ssservice.add(0, "Select District");
        district
                .setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
                        ssservice));

        // Spinner on item click listener
        district
                .setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0,
                                               View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        //  ed_spinner = district.getSelectedItem().toString();
                        if (!(position == 0)) {
                            //district.getSelectedItem().get(position).getSpinnerDistrictId();
                             spinnerDistrictId = service.get(position).getSpinnerDistrictId();
                            Log.e("Spinner district id", ""+spinnerDistrictId);
                            new NetCheck2().execute();
                        }


                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    }
                });

        return;
    }
```

I have used setter and getter to set these values. Now I want the id of the selected spinner item which i have set. I tried using

```
    spinnerDistrictId = service.get(position).getSpinnerDistrictId();
```

But not getting the id.

How to get this id.. Please help me..

Comment: what are you getting in the `Log` ?

Comment: @SatyenUdeshi i am getting null

Comment: While clicking on any other item also gives null ?

Comment: Can you log `service.size()` and see what it prints /

Comment: @SatyenUdeshi It is 4

Comment: See i have added an answer for that, problem you are facing as first you add data to `service` object and then you clearing that, and in your next `for` loop once again you are adding data but this time you are not setting `district id` so it is giving null, in answer i have mentioned the lines that needs to be commented please check and let me know if helps

Answer (score 0):

See in your first `for` loop you are adding data to `service` and then your are clearing it

```
 for (int i=0;i<set.size();i++) {
        pojo = new Pojo();
        pojo.setSpinnerDistrict(titlesList.get(i));
        pojo.setSpinnerDistrictId(descList.get(i));
        service.add(pojo);
       // ssservice.add(p);
    }
    service.clear(); // here comment this line
```

and in your other `for` loop dont add data to `service` object or else it will create duplicate entries...

```
 for (String p : set) {
        pojo = new Pojo();

        pojo.setSpinnerDistrict(p);
        service.add(pojo); // comment this line
        ssservice.add(p);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks but i have a problem.. I have added  ssservice.add(0, "Select District"); at first position so positions are not proper

Comment: and also i am getting title values as id no ids

Comment: Actually what you are doing is not the proper way you should write a custom adapter that holds both id and title and attach that to `spinner` :)